# Extending timeout and message size in WCF service generated by Biztalk 2006 R2

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I'm generating WCF service using Biztalk. The code I get is this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" externalMetadataLocation="" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
        <endpoint name="HttpMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <!--<endpoint name="HttpsMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Maybe it's not the most beautifull configuration, but it works. The problem is I don't know how to modify timeouts and message max size, because it has only mex endpoint. I'm surprised how this works at all with just mex endpoint.

So two questions are:

1. Why does this works at all?
2. What should I add to extend timeouts and message size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to recall the reason those settings aren't in the config file is because the binding configuration is stored in the receive location / send port settings in biztalk itself. So the way to set them is to change them from the receive location adapter configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. I was creating a msbuild script and thought that I should update location web.config after publishing WCF service but it appeared that I had to modify binding info, which is actually much easier